# CUDA fmod - calling a __host__ function from a __global__ function is not allowed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I'm compiling a CUDA 5 project with VS2012 and I'm receiving this error:

```
error : calling a __host__ function("fmod<float, int> ") from a __global__ function is not allowed
```

The compiler is practically mismatching the CUDA __device__ fmod with the fmod defined in math.h

How can I "disambiguate" between them?

Comment: Did you include math.h?

Comment: No, but it's probably included somewhere else. It's a large project and I'm just a part of it

Comment: There is no fmod(float,int) variant supported on the device side, so the compiler finds only the host-side version, which can't be called from the device. CUDA supports the following overloaded variants: fmod(float,float), fmod(double,double). It should be trivial to map your case to one of these.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because of a template argument mismatch. You are calling `fmod` with a floating point argument and an integer argument. There is only a device template argument for a pair of single precision or double precision floating point arguments (see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1g5e4d96de745c62d885d0a3a6bc838b86)).

What you are probably looking for is `fmod(float, (float)int)`....